# RMarkdown chunk output in console preview does not display latex option `\textcolor{}`

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown

In Rmarkdown, I use the `\textcolor` option inside latex code, by writing:

```
$$
\textcolor{red}{This is Red}
$$
```

which when compiled will show `This is Red` but in red color. However, the "chunk output in console" preview option does NOT load this. Does anyone know of a quick fix? I've attached what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Rmd document in RStudio, you can use `\color` that is recognized in Latex equation block in RStudio

```
$$
\color{red}{This is Red}
$$
```

I got this

[image]

It renders in Red too in the pdf document.